# Android setText() method causes activity to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android and I'm having issues on filling a textView for displaying an error message. 
In RSSReader service, in doInBackground() method, when it fails to get the data from the url given by NewsActivity, it should set some message in the TextView errorMessage, and it works only if the given url is not an url at all, otherwise the activity crashes.

I don't understand why the method setText() does not always work.

This is ReadRss service class

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String address;
URL url;
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Dialog dialog;
NewsActivity newsActivity;


public ReadRss(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, String address, NewsActivity newsActivity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.address = address;
    this.newsActivity = newsActivity;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() { //prima di caricare i dati mostro il dialog

    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.e("POST EXECUTE", "E' ENTRATO");

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(feedItems, context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    if(getData()!=null){

        processXml(getData());
    }else {

        Log.e("DET DATA NULL", "E' ENTRATO");
        feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        newsActivity.setErrorMessage("Invalid Url, Please delete this feed and create one with a valid url");
    }

    return null;
}



// In this method we will process Rss feed  document we downloaded to parse useful information from it
private void processXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {

        feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cureentchild = items.item(i);
            if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                        item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
                feedItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }else{

        feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public  Document getData(){
    try {
        url = new URL(address);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);

        return xmlDocument;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And this NewsActivity Class

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
String url;
TextView errorMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    url = bundle.getString("Url");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNewsActivity);
    errorMessage = findViewById(R.id.error_message);

    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(this, recyclerView,url, this);
    readRss.execute();
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage){

    this.errorMessage.setText(errorMessage);
}

}
```

I hope I was clear, and thank you for your help

Comment: change `errorMessage = findViewById(R.id.error_message);` to `errorMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error_message);`

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: just to make sure you are not showing any number into textview, it cause to error and activity close. if need to show number than do like this `textview.setText(number+"");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I entered only one string :(

Comment: than check string is not null  @Knospfer

Comment: I fixed the issue. I didn't know that onBackground() method can't touch the UI, i added a boolean for cecking if there is some wrong url, then in onPostExecute() I set the TextMessage text

Comment: good work :) yeah, onBckground run in child thread do not have permission to use ui